# Problemas ao ocultar/exibir div com Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Estou com um problema relativamente simples, mas que não encontro uma solução rápida: tenho um `dropdownlist` que determina qual *div* será exibida, e no momento que a página é carregada pela primeira vez, funciona perfeitamente. Logo após salvar os dados (ou seja, dar *refresh* na página), a opção que ficou oculta antes desse *refresh* não é exibida mais ao ser selecionada no `dropdownlist` .

A função abaixo é chamada ao selecionar o `dropdownlist` . Logo abaixo, o `dropdownlist` onde chamo a função.

OBS.: Já tentei usando jQuery, já tentei chamando o evento no *PostBack* da página (e fora dele também), mas a impressão que fica é que minha div se perde em algum momento.

Também já tentei colocando o `display:none/block` direto na *div*, sem sucesso. As duas *divs* estão fixas no `.aspx`, e não são feitas dinamicamente.

OBS. 2: Dentro da `divParcelaVariavel`, existem dois `UpdatePanel`, usados em dois botões.

```
function MudarEstado() {

     var fixas = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder2_divParcelaFixas');
     var variaveis = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder2_divParcelaVariavel');


     if (document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder2_dropTipoParcelas').value == 'V') {
         variaveis.style.display = 'block'
         fixas.style.display = 'none'
        }
     else {
         variaveis.style.display = 'none'
         fixas.style.display = 'block'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Não entendi bem sua pergunta, mas utilize o console do navegador para verificar o estilo da `div`.

Comment: Basicamente é o seguinte: tenho duas divs, "Parcela Fixa" e "Parcela Variavel". Se, por exemplo, eu seleciono a Variavel primeiro e salvo, apos esse postback a div de Fixa não é renderizada na tela ao ser selecionada no meu drop. No codigo-fonte da página ela aparece, mas na tela, não. E vi atraves de debug que esse elemento (document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder2_divParcelaFixas') retorna null.

Comment: Sua função MudarEstado está dentro de um $(document).ready(function(){ }); ? Quando você inspeciona a página você encontra essa div??

Comment: Não está não, mas eu encontro a div sim. Ela está lá mas não é exibida.

Comment: O engraçado é esse retorno null, mesmo sendo carregada internamente...

Comment: Poe no console document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder2_divParcelaFixas') pra ver se retorna null. A proposito o nome é ContentPlaceHolder2_divParcelaFixas ou ContentPlaceHolder2_divParcelaFixa?

Comment: Retornou null. O nome é ContentPlaceHolder2_divParcelaFixas. Digitando document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder2_divParcelaVariavel') ele trouxe <div id="ContentPlaceHolder2_divParcelaVariavel" class="caixa2" style="display: none;">.

Comment: <div id="ContentPlaceHolder2_divParcelaFixas" class="caixa2">
        <fieldset>
            <legend><b>Parcela fixa</b></legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style9">Número de Parcelas</td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$textNumeroParcelas" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder2_textNumeroParcelas" onKeyPress="javascript:campoNumerico(this);" style="width:50px;" />
                    </td>
Segue acima um trechinho do "Exibir código-fonte", provando que ele está lá.

Comment: Ele retorna null, porém inspecionando você encontra... Que estranho.. Pensei que poderia ter digitado errado o id...

Comment: Pode ser que você esteja tentando localizar a div antes de ela existir. Ou tem mesmo algum erro de digitação como imaginou o @JoaoPaulo.

Comment: @bfavaretto Imaginei que ela tentou localizar antes de existir, mas ela disse que não é dinamica e mesmo rodando o codigo no console com a div já lá retornou null.

Comment: O que pensei ter acontecido é o seguinte: No momento que a página carrega, eu por exemplo escolho a div Variaveis e oculto a Fixa. Quando salvo e volto pra tela, ele entende que a div Fixa ainda precisa ficar oculta e mostra apenas a Variaveis. Existe alguma forma de eu "zerar" esse estado das divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UpdatePanel` é uma atualização de uma pedaço da tela.
Se somente um pedaço da tela é atualizada você acaba perdendo seu Javascript/Jquery, perdendo a função que seu Dropdown executa, dê um lida [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels) para melhor entender.
Use o código abaixo para um novo carregamento da função Javascript  após uma atualização de bloco.

```
 var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
     prm.add_endRequest(function () {
       $("#dpw").click(function () {     
        mudarEstado();
      });
    });
```

E matenha Aqui.

```
$(function () {
 mudarEstado();
});
```

Sua function JavaScript deverá ficar da seguinte forma.
Decidi colocar o select e option pois no fim Dropdown e ListItem se não tornam o mesmo para o navegador.

Segue exemplo de como deve ser feito..

```html
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <select id="dpw" onclick="mudarEstado()">
                <option selected="selected" value="S">Ocultar</option>
                <option value="N">Mostrar</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <div id="oculta" style="display:none;background-color: #000; width: 30px; height: 40px"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function mudarEstado() {
            var value = document.getElementById("dpw").value;
            if (value === "S")
                document.getElementById("oculta").style.display = "none";
            else
                document.getElementById("oculta").style.display = "block";
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Nenhuma das opções funcionou... ele chama a função mas volta pra página sem exibir a div =/ 
Muito obrigada pela ajuda!

Comment: Vou postar os trechos pertinentes, a página é bem extensa. Vale uma observação: Existe nessa página um contador de tempo de conexão, também feito em Javascript. 

Declaração do DropDownList: 
 <td class="style9">Parcelas </td><td><asp:DropDownList ID="dropTipoParcelas"runat="server"onchange="javascript:MudarEstado();"><asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem> <asp:ListItem Value="F" Text="Fixa"></asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Value="V" Text="Variáveis"></asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList>

Comment: Vi sim, já usei aqueles exemplos em outras telas do sistema mas nesse caso não ajudou, infelizmente.

Comment: Função MudarEstado: 
  function MudarEstado() { var fixas = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder2_divParcelaFixas'); var variaveis =document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder2_divParcelaVariavel');
 if document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder2_dropTipoParcelas').value == 'V') {variaveis.style.display = 'block'
 fixas.style.display = 'none'}else { variaveis.style.display = 'none' fixas.style.display = 'block'
                }
            }

Comment: Tentei uma chamada a essa função no PostBack da pagina, tambem sem sucesso: 

  function EstadoLoad() {
            alert("entrei");
document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder2_divParcelaVariavel').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder2_divParcelaFixas').style.display = 'block';
        }

Comment: No PostBack da página: 

  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "MudarEstado",
                  "EstadoLoad();",
                  true);

Comment: Sem reputação suficiente pra chat ¬¬

Comment: @ArethaFreitas Vamos excluir os comentários?